# Standalone in subfile

Tags: standalone, subfiles

I am trying to do  cirkuittikz diagram inside a subfile but if i compile main it does not work.

main:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usepackage{subfiles}

\begin{document}
    \subfile{include/chapter1}
\end{document}
```

chapter1.tex:

```
\documentclass[../main.tex]{subfiles}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Test}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includestandalone{figure/fig}
    \caption{A figure.}
    \label{fig:fig}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

fig.tex:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz}
        \draw[] (0,0)
        to[R]++(0,3)
        ;
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

LaTeX Error: Can be used only in preamble.

You have used a command in the main body of your document which should be used in the preamble. Make sure that \documentclass[…]{…} and all \usepackage{…} commands are written before \begin{document}.
 Learn more

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H   for immediate help.
 ...

l.2 \usepackage
               {circuitikz}
Your command was ignored.
Type  I    to replace it with another command,
or    to continue without it.

)
File: figure/fig.tex Graphic file (type tex)
) (/compile/include/chapter2.tex [1

Comment: I believe that you would simply write `\input{figure/fig}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of version v1.6 of `subfiles`, this incompatibility of `subfiles` and the `standalone` package is fixed, your example now compiles fine. The version is currently only available on [Github](https://github.com/gsalzer/subfiles), but will make it sooner or later also to CTAN (I have to give the people there a break, published too many updates within the last week ;-).

Comment: Works perfectly. However, standalone needs to be loaded before subfiles.

Comment: Yes, this is right, the docs also say so. The `standalone` package modifies the `\document` command, and the `subfiles` package needs to conserve the modified version to restore it later correctly. As a general rule, `subfiles` should be loaded last.

Answer (score 1):

After looking over this package for the last 45 minutes, I recommend not mixing subfiles and standalone. I have not been able to make them work.

For some reason while loading a `\input{standalone}` while inside a `\subfile{mysubfile}` it will print all names of the used packages. This seems like an incompatibility, as by its design, the standalone package is supposed to exclude these. Here is an example of the error.

main.tex

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[mode=tex]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{subfiles}

\begin{document}

\subfile{chapter1}

And now the figure by itself \input{fig}

\end{document}
```

chapter1.tex

```
\documentclass[main.tex]{subfiles}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Test}

\input{fig}

\end{document}
```

fig.tex

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz}
        \draw[] (0,0) to [R] ++(0,3);
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image: take note of the erroneous circuitikz]

Take note of the erroneous circuitikz word right before the first figure.

As a solution, dont use the standalone package; set your `fig.tex` file to this, and use the above code for `main.tex` and `chapter1.tex`

new fig.tex

```
\begin{circuitikz}
    \draw[] (0,0) to [R] ++(0,3);
\end{circuitikz}
```

Comment: As a side note, I was never actually ever to re-create your error. Which leads me to believe you are either using windows (and it might be a / \ related error), or had your file paths set up wrong. Based upon your inital code you had better had your file structure look like this. 
 root directory |- main.tex
  | directory named include |- chapter1.tex
  | directory named figure |- fig.tex
where include and figure directories are in the root.

Comment: Your example (like the one from the OP) now works without errors with `subfiles` 1.6 or later. Thanks for your investigations.